# Fragment customAnimation not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have below code for setting enter and exit animations for fragments.

```
final FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
final FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
    ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

**slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="@integer/slide_anim_duration" />

</set>
```

Used same method for all other animations. Works fine in all other versions, but the problem is in Lollipop only. As we look in to the function 
`setCustomAnimations (int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)` [doc-link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) , 
`enter` and `exit` works fine, but `popEnter` and `popExit` fails in Lollipop.
 Please guide me about what went wrong and provide a compatible solution that works from Android **2.3 to 5.1**

**Update:**

Observing closely,it seems that the animation is there, but the duration has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried other animations to check if the problem is in this specific `slide_in_left.xml` one?

Comment: Also, have you tested on different devices? Does the problem happen on an emulator?

Comment: @Ricardo Yes, I'm using so many animations like that one. All are working fine except with `popEnter` and `popExit` in lollipop. Problem is in devices with Lollipop. Didn't try emulator.

Comment: I have almost the same kind of transaction in a project of mine that is working fine. The only two things different are: 1) I'm passing `null` to `addToBackStack()` and 2) I'm using `commit()` instead of `commitAllowingStateLoss()`.

Comment: Works fine on API 22 and API 16. The problem is device specific, or could be connected with the unlisted animation files.

Answer (score 3):

Fragment animations are broken even before L - there are some issues when changing screen orientation.

Below solution fixes both L issues and earlier orientation change issues. Use it as your base Fragment class.

```java
public abstract class AnimatedSupportFragment extends DaggerFragment {

    private static final String STATE_ENTER_ANIM = "STATE_ENTER_ANIM";
    private static final String STATE_EXIT_ANIM = "STATE_EXIT_ANIM";
    private static final String STATE_POP_ENTER_ANIM = "STATE_POP_ENTER_ANIM";
    private static final String STATE_POP_EXIT_ANIM = "STATE_POP_EXIT_ANIM";
    private static final String STATE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS = "STATE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS";

    private @AnimRes int mEnter = 0;
    private @AnimRes int mExit = 0;
    private @AnimRes int mPopEnter = 0;
    private @AnimRes int mPopExit = 0;
    private boolean mIsChangingConfigurations = false;

    public void setCustomAnimations(@AnimRes int enterAnim,
                                    @AnimRes int exitAnim,
                                    @AnimRes int popEnterAnim,
                                    @AnimRes int popExitAnim) {
        mEnter = enterAnim;
        mExit = exitAnim;
        mPopEnter = popEnterAnim;
        mPopExit = popExitAnim;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mEnter = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ENTER_ANIM);
            mExit = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_EXIT_ANIM);
            mPopEnter = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POP_ENTER_ANIM);
            mPopExit = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POP_EXIT_ANIM);
            mIsChangingConfigurations = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS);
        }
    }

    @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_ENTER_ANIM, mEnter);
        outState.putInt(STATE_EXIT_ANIM, mExit);
        outState.putInt(STATE_POP_ENTER_ANIM, mPopEnter);
        outState.putInt(STATE_POP_EXIT_ANIM, mPopExit);
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS, mIsChangingConfigurations);
    }

    @Override public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mIsChangingConfigurations = false;
    }

    @Override public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            mIsChangingConfigurations = getActivity().isChangingConfigurations();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {

        // This implementation fixes loosing transition animations on orientation changes:
        // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837408/fragment-lost-transition-animation-after-configuration-change
        // @see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25994&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Do not support animations PRE-3.0, isChangingConfigurations() is not available!
            return null;
        }

        try {
            int anim;
            if (mIsChangingConfigurations) {
                // Recreating after change configuration, we don't want to play animation
                anim = 0;
            } else if (nextAnim != 0) {
                // Animation available (not lost) -> play it!
                anim = nextAnim;
            } else {
                // Animation probably lost - load anim saved in fragment state.
                // enter = we're about to play popEnterAnim, in other case popExitAnimation
                anim = enter ? mPopEnter : mPopExit;
            }
            if (anim != 0) {
                return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), anim);
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the values for STATE_ENTER_ANIM etc arbitrary or did you get them from looking at the android source? From the lack of upvotes I can only assume people are not using fragment transition animations that much, nice work.

Comment: I'm using this code in many projects and it works like a charm :) What are the symptoms? What is your use case? How did you create your fragment transaction?

Answer (score 1):

you can additionally try onCreateAnimator in all the fragments..or the base fragment that they are extending...

```
@target_api 20 or higher

@Override
    public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
        if (enter) {
            return AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.slide_in_top);
        } else {
            return AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.fade_out);
        }
    }
```

**Note** both above animators are pre defined and R there is android.R

Hope this helps 
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the duration to 2000 you will see the animation, but I think it's too slow. This is my code:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

You can put less duration, but you will see less animation.

Answer (score 0):

I find an other solution, it not makes exactly the same animation, but is very similar, I like this animation more than the traditional slide this is my code for do the animation:

```
     private Fragment fragment=new Fragment();
 private FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();


private void replaceFragmentWithAnimation(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && fragment != null) {
            Slide slideLeft = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
            slideLeft.setDuration(300);
            fragment.setExitTransition(slideLeft);
        }

        fragment = CalendarFragment.newInstance(selectedDays, plusMonths);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Slide slideRight = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
            slideRight.setDuration(350);
            fragment.setEnterTransition(slideRight);

        } else {
           ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
        ft.replace(calendarDaysContFL.getId(), fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution:
Modified version of @jskierbi answer.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;


/**
 * @author : Pedramrn@gmail.com Created on: 2016-02-19
 */
public class SupportBaseFragment extends Fragment {

private boolean mIsChangingConfigurations = false;
private static final String STATE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS = "STATE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS";

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mIsChangingConfigurations = false;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mIsChangingConfigurations = getActivity().isChangingConfigurations();
}


@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    if (mIsChangingConfigurations)
        return null;
    if (enter)
        return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), nextAnim == 0 ? R.anim.enter_pop : nextAnim);
    else
        return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), nextAnim == 0 ? R.anim.exit_pop : nextAnim);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mIsChangingConfigurations = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS, mIsChangingConfigurations);
}
```

enter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

enter_pop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

exit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
</set>
```

exit_pop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%"/>
</set>
```

Usage:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit,
                        R.anim.enter_pop, R.anim.exit_pop)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFancyFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```